JOLT parse date and datetime to ISO Format
Within a given JSON I have to adapt Dates to an ISO format, and I do not get the right approach.
This is my input JSON :
{
  "itemNo": "1010333",
  "productNo": "myProduct",
  "description": "myItem-01",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "identifier": "FIRST_DATE",
      "type": "attribute",
      "DataType": "DATE",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "05.12.2022"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "identifier": "mytimestamp",
      "type": "attribute",
      "DataType": "DATEANDTIME",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "17.07.2023 13:13:10"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

and this is the desired output
when DataType is DATE => parse String of value to yyyy_MM-ss
when DataType is DATEANDTIME => parse String of value to yyyy_MM-ss'T'hh:mm:ss
{
  "itemNo": "1010333",
  "productNo": "myProduct",
  "description": "myItem-01",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "identifier": "FIRST_DATE",
      "type": "attribute",
      "DataType": "DATE",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "2022-12-05"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "identifier": "mytimestamp",
      "type": "attribute",
      "DataType": "DATEANDTIME",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "2023-07-17'T'13:13:10"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Unfortuantely I cannot provide the slightest approach here, because I do not know wether to start with "shift" or with "modify-overwrite-beta", due to the fact, that all depends on the DataType.
If it is not a good idea to transform Dates within JOLT I can try it with another nifi processor.Currently my aim is, to proceed as much as possible with JOLT. Thanks in advance for your opinion.

You can handle the issue by using modify-overwrite-beta tarnsformations in which you can start with manipulating the strings by substring and concat functions, and then check out the existence of the hour:minute:second portion through use of ? operator such as in the following case :
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "attributes": {
        "*": {
          "values": {
            "*": {
              "day_": "=substring(@(1,value),0,2)",
              "mon_": "=substring(@(1,value),3,5)",
              "year_": "=substring(@(1,value),6,10)",
              "hour_": "=substring(@(1,value),11,19)",
              "value": "=concat(@(1,year_),'-',@(1,mon_),'-',@(1,day_))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //adhere 'T' through checking existence of the attribute
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "attributes": {
        "*": {
          "values": {
            "*": {
              "hour_?": "=concat(''T'',@(1,&))", // occurs only if the "hour_" attribute exists
              "value": "=concat(@(1,&),@(1,hour_))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//get rid of the attributes end with underscores
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*_": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Like always : my greatest respect . What an excellent idea to remove the calculating attributes..!!

No worries @KatjaBürger , indeed, keep in mind that there might be an alternative way of solution which would contain formatiing through expression language within JoltTransformJSON processor but that would need many stuffs for preparation such as SplitJSON, EvaluateJSONPath, UpdateRecord processors along with some control structures and long schemas.  So I preferred directly use of JoltTransformJSON with this chain spec. Regards.
